# Passing by referencing with a function in php?

Tags: php

I have a simple function like so which I use to compare something,

```
function life($life) {
    while($life) {
        echo $life . '<br />';
        --$life;
    }
    return $life;
}
$life = life($user['lifeforce']);
if($life) { ... }
```

Should I pass it by reference or forget it and use what I am using? Would it be better to do...

```
function life(&$life) {
    while($life) {
        echo $life . '<br />';
        --$life;
    }
}
life($user['lifeforce']);
if($user['lifeforce']) { ... }
```

I am not quite understading the concepts of passing by reference?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need to pass by reference here, and if you don't need to then don't because it will require that you keep in mind that variable could change value when the function is called.  It is normally much better to avid references in php unless you need them.

Comment: What I am trying to grasp is when I need to use them? When is a good use for them?!

Comment: So if you have a giant array which is too big to copy and hold both in memory then it might be worth it.  print_r for example doesn't use them but var_dump does so if you have an array that completely fills memory you would have to use var_dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first make sure that you read [php manual on references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), especially the part about [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Simple example:

```
function integer_division( $number, $divider, &$remain){
  $remain = $number%$divider;
  return floor( $number/$divider);
}

$remain = 0;
$result = integer_division( 5, 2, $remain);
// $remain now contains 1
```

You should use reference ONLY when you intend to change value original variable (for example array sort functions work that way), or you need to return more than 1 value (and returning an array is a bad option).

So to answer your question directly: you should probably use the first way (unless you want to have 0 in userlife).

Comment: I have lots of functions that return arrays in my code should I change it to pass by reference? And thanks this has helped :)

Comment: @cgwebprojects that's worth another question, but generally when you use reference to return multiple values you just access preallocated memory, whether when returning array you have to allocate place for `1..N` scalars. (Returning complex objects used later is completely different thing.) I'm really not sure what overhead does it bring and whether it's worth to rewrite functions. I also like `class A { function getResultPartA(); function getResultPartB(); function calculateResult();}` ... Don't change it because of this answer, ask another question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will leave them be for now, my code isn't slow or anything so why change it, if it becomes a problem later on at least I know what might be causing it so thanks for that.